# Should I initialize a shared_ptr inside or outside the class constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Given the following example code:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::shared_ptr<int> p);
private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
};

Foo::Foo(std::shared_ptr<int> p) : ptr(std::move(p)) {
}

class Bar {
public:
    Bar(int &p);
private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
};

Bar::Bar(int &p) : ptr(std::make_shared<int>(p)) {
}

int main() {
    Foo foo(std::make_shared<int>(int(256)));
    Bar bar(*new int(512));

    return 0;
}
```

Both Foo and Bar work correctly. However, are there any differences between creating the shared_ptr when calling the constructor and then transferring ownership with std::move and just passing a reference to the object and delegating the creation of the shared_ptr to the class constructor?

I assume the second way is better since I don't have to move the pointer. However, I've mostly seen the first way being used in the code I'm reading.

Which one should I use and why?

Comment: I prefer the direct-initialization with `std::make_shared`. If `new` throws you have a definite memory leak.

Comment: The code leaks memory, the two things are completely different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Foo is correct.

Bar is an abomination. It involves a memory leak, unsafe exception behaviour and an un-necessary copy.

EDIT: explanation of memory leak.

Deconstructing this line:

```
Bar bar(*new int(512));
```

results in these operations:

1. call new int(512) which results in a call to operator new, returning a pointer to an int on the heap (memory allocation).
2. dereference the pointer in order to provide a const reference for the constructor of Bar
3. Bar then constructs its shared_ptr with one returned by make_shared (this part is efficient). This shared_ptr's int is initialised with a copy of the int passed by reference.
4. then the function returns, but since no variable has recorded the pointer returned from new, nothing can free the memory. Every new must be mirrored by a delete in order to destroy the object and deallocate its memory.
5. therefore memory leak

Comment: Can you argument better the "memory leak" and "exeption unsafety"?

Comment: That's fine, but the problem is not Bar itself, but the way it has been used. But you state the abnomination is Bar, while the real problem is *new (that makes the pointer returned by new unavailable and hence undeletable)

Comment: That's fair. There is a further ideological problem with the constructor of Bar - it takes a non-const reference. That gives the signal that it intends to modify the int being referenced - it also means it can't be initialised from a const int.

Comment: Uhmm... not really "ideological": it might had been the reason that pushed the OP to try `*new int`, since passing just 512 did not work, since it cannot be a L-Reference.

Comment: When I write "ideological problem", it's my tactful way of saying, "totally wrong" :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

If you need a `shared_ptr` internally, because you want to share the object with some other objects your create later, the second way may be better (except for that horrible constructor call obviously).

If you want shared ownership of an existing object (this is the more common case, really), you don't have a choice and you need to use the first way.

If neither of these applies, you probably don't need a `shared_ptr` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The second way is incorrect; it leaks memory. With

```
Bar::Bar(int &p) : ptr(std::make_shared<int>(p)) {
}

....

Bar bar(*new int(512));
```

the `shared_ptr` made by `std::make_shared` takes the value of `p` (which is `512`) to build a new shared pointer that's responsible for a new piece of memory; it does not accept responsibility for the memory address where `p` lies. This piece -- the one you allocated in `main` -- is then lost. This particular piece of code would work with

```
                        // +---------------------- building a shared_ptr directly
                        // v                v----- from p's address
Bar::Bar(int &p) : ptr(std::shared_ptr<int>(&p)) {
```

...but look at that. **That is pure evil.** Nobody expects that a reference parameter to a constructor requires that it references a heap object of which the new object will take responsibility.

You could more sanely write

```
Bar::Bar(int *p) : ptr(p) {
}

....

Bar bar(new int(512));
```

In fact you could give `Foo` a second constructor that does that, if you wanted. It's a bit of an argument how clear the function signature makes it that the pointer has to be to a heap-allocated object, but `std::shared_ptr` offers the same, so there's precedent. It depends on what your class does whether this is a good idea.

Comment: Why let the user do the heap allocation in the first place though? You could just as easily take the argument by non-owning (rvalue) reference and copy (move) it into the `shared_ptr` in the `Bar` case.

Comment: One reason you might want to have it is because you need to take ownership from `std::unique_ptr`s, or to deal with legacy code that uses `std::auto_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr`. Sometimes you can't pick your libraries freely, and then something like this can cut down on boilerplate code. It's not a facility you'd use often, probably, but it can make sense to have it in place. Sometimes.

Comment: Good point. In that case however I'd argue that the `Foo` approach is preferable, which makes it more obvious that ownership is passed to the object's constructor. Still, nice analysis on why the original code for `Bar` was broken.

Comment: `std::make_shared<int>(&p)` won't work either. `std::shared_ptr<int>(&p)` would.

Answer (score 0):

Both can work correctly, but the way you use them in `main` is not consistent.

When I see a constructor taking a reference (like `Bar(int& p)`) I expect Bar to hold a reference. When I see `Bar(const int& p)` I expect it to hold a copy.
When I see a rvalue ref (not universal, like `Bar(int&& p)` I expect p not "surviving its content" after passed. (well... for an it that's not that meaningful...).

In any case `p` holds an `int`, not a `pointer`, and what make_shared expects are the parameter to forwarded to the int constructor (that is ... an int, not int*).

Your main so have to be

```
Foo foo(std::make_shared<int>(int(256)));
Bar bar(512);
```

This will make bar to hold a dynamically allocated sharable copy of the value `512`.

If you do `Bar bar(*new int(512))` you make bar to hold a copy of your "new int", whose pointer gets discarded, and hence the int itself leaked.

In general, expressions like `*new something` should sound as "no no no no no ..."

But you `Bar` constructor has a problem: to be able to take a constant or an expression returned value, it must take a `const int&`, not an `int&`

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to take sole ownership of a heap-allocated object I suggest you accept a `std::unique_ptr`. It documents the intention clearly and you can create a `std::shared_ptr` from the `std::unique_ptr` internally if you need to:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<int> p);
private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
};

Foo::Foo(std::unique_ptr<int> p) : ptr(std::move(p)) {
}

int main() {
    Foo foo(std::make_unique<int>(512));
}
```

Don't do `Bar`, it is error prone and fails to describe your intent (if I understand your intent correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you used `int` just as an example, and there is a real resource instead, then it depends on what you want to achieve.

The first is a typical dependency injection, where the object is injected through the constructor. It's good side is that it can simplify unit testing.

The second case just creates the object in the constructor, and initializes it using values passed through the constructor.

---

By the way, take care how you initialize. This :

```
Bar bar(*new int(512));
```

is causing a memory leak. A memory is allocated, but never deallocated.